# How do i use the printf command with more than one string and arg?

Tags: java

I have written a object that creates a rectangle in java (eclipse), but when i try to print out the information about the rectangle I get a wired error.

This works fine, but is not to pleasant to lock at, since it returns a value with 14 digits after ","

```
System.out.println("Rectangle2\t Width: " + rectangle2.width + "\tHeight: " + 
            rectangle2.height + "\tArea: " + rectangle2.getArea() + "\tPerimiter: " + rectangle2.getPerimiter());
```

While this prints it with two digits after "`,`", which is what I'm trying to accomplish. But it only prints the first string and number and results in an error.

```
    System.out.printf("Rectangle2\t Width: %.2f%n", rectangle2.width, "\tHeight: %.2f%n", 
            rectangle2.height + "\tArea: %.2f%n", rectangle2.getArea() + "\tPerimiter: %.2f%n", rectangle2.getPerimiter());
```

If i only use "`,`" instead of "`+`" the error don't come up, but it still only prints the first string and number. How do I print it with `%.2f%n` without most of it disappearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of `printf` is the format String and all the other parameters are the arguments to format the String.

```
System.out.printf("Rectangle2\t Width: %.2f%n\tHeight: %.2f%n\tArea: %.2f%n\tPerimiter: %.2f%n", rectangle2.width,rectangle2.height, rectangle2.getArea(),rectangle2.getPerimiter());
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thanks for the help